# List items from HTML XPath

Tags: javascript, html, xpath

I need to list items returned from evaluating an Xpath. I'd like to return the tweets in a list, so I can further evaluate their elements. How do I do this?

My code is:

```js
var navigable_stream = '//*[@id="stream-items-id"]'; 
var FIRST_RECORD = document.evaluate(navigable_stream, document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null).iterateNext();
console.log(FIRST_RECORD);
```

And the returned HTML is very long. But it has lots of tweets with different ids. Here's a picture to show what I mean:
 [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

> *" Is there a way to match the first part of the element id i.e. 'stream-item-tweet"?"*

Yes, by using referencing the partial #id as an attribute:

```
var tweet = document.querySelectorAll("[id^=stream-item-tweet]");
```

Note the `^=` means that the ***beginning of the #id*** must match `stream-item-tweet`

Having answered the question I'd like to add that there may be a better alternative by using the class of each `<li>`:

```
var tweet = document.querySelectorAll('.js-stream-item')
```

Something looks invalid on the classList:

```
class="js-stream-item stream-item stream-item"
```

`.stream-item` is repeated twice...maybe it's best to avoid class in your circumstance.

Anyways, knowing the first way should work and maybe the second way might, `tweet` is now a **NodeList** which needs to be handled by a loop or it needs to be converted to an array so it can be processed by an array method.

**Demo 2** shows how the latter is done.

---

Just guessing, since there's no way I can test it myself, that if that's what you can get on the console, then you could maybe use `.toString()` then parse and append it to the DOM.

---

### Demo 1

**Not possible to make an actual functioning Demo**

---

```js
var navigable_stream = '//*[@id="stream-items-id"]';
var FIRST_RECORD = document.evaluate(navigable_stream, document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null).iterateNext();
console.log(FIRST_RECORD);

var str = FIRST_RECORD.toString();

document.getElementById('dock01').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', str);
```

```html
<section id='dock01'></section>
```

---

### Demo 2

---

```js
/* Collect all elements with an #id that starts with "tweet"
|| Convert NodeList into an array
*/
var tweets = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("[id^=tweet]"));

/* filter() the array tweets
|| if an item has data-id = "retweet"
|| add it to the new array retweets
*/
var retweets = tweets.filter(function(t) {
  return t.dataset.id === "retweet";
});

console.log(retweets);
```

```css
/* The lazy way to add text */

li::after {
  content: attr(id);
}


/* This is just so the console results don't obscure the Demo*/

.as-console-wrapper {
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: 30%;
}

.as-console-row:after {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li id='tweet-51515151' data-id='retweet'></li>
  <li id='tweet-57885157' data-id='tweet'></li>
  <li id='tweet-51677459' data-id='tweet'></li>
  <li id='tweet-51890331' data-id='retweet'></li>
  <li id='tweet-51515337' data-id='retweet'></li>
  <li id='tweet-51593051' data-id='retweet'></li>
  <li id='tweet-51333333' data-id='tweet'></li>
  <li id='tweet-51534152' data-id='tweet'></li>
  <li id='tweet-51599951' data-id='tweet'></li>
  <li id='tweet-54785151' data-id='retweet'></li>
  <li id='tweet-56785199' data-id='retweet'></li>
  <li id='tweet-51557844' data-id='tweet'></li>
  <li id='tweet-51510000' data-id='retweet'></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The problem is that I have lots of tweets, with lots of different ids. Is there a way to match the first part of the element id i.e. 'stream-item-tweet"?

Comment: Indeed there is a way, I'll update the answer in a moment.